# Scrollify (jquery) - disable plugin on some pages at the site (newbie)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to use scrollify for my website (Wordpress, woocomerce) [www.chame-lemon.com](https://chame-lemon.com) and I'm totally green in programming, so I really need your help guys.

I need to disable the plugin on shop page and product pages, I'm using a class named "hwdp" to all sections on the pages when I want to use plugin. but he is activated on other pages because of the footer (it has a class to turn on scrollify also) but I can't use two separate footers in Wordpress, so I need to use code with using a function

```
$.scrollify.disable();        
The disable method turns off the scroll snap behavior so that the page scroll like normal.
```

there is documentation for that plugin
https://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/#methods-continued

that should look like that:
if there is no class named hwdp on the page
the plugin should be disable
else
he should be enabled

and I tried to fix that by myself, I spend hours and i got no results... and i know that's a very simple thing for someone who knows jquery.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$.scrollify({ 
    section : ".hwdp",
    interstitialSection: ".footer",
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    scrollSpeed: 1200,
    offset: 1,
    scrollbars: true,
    standardScrollElements: "",
    setHeights: true,
    overflowScroll: true,
    updateHash: true,
    touchScroll: false,
    before:function() {},
    after:function() {},
    afterResize:function() {},
    afterRender:function() {},

 });

if (!$('section').hasClass('.hwdp')) {
$.scrollify.enable();
  }else{
$.scrollify.disable();
  } 

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the plugin is being initialized on every page regardless of whether it finds the `.hwdp` class. It's better to only be initialized when it needs to be.

Here's how you can enable the plugin only when there exists a `section` on the page with the class `.hwdp`.

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  if($('section.hwdp').length) {

    $.scrollify({ 
      section : ".hwdp",
      interstitialSection: ".footer",
      easing: "easeOutExpo",
      scrollSpeed: 1200,
      offset: 1,
      scrollbars: true,
      standardScrollElements: "",
      setHeights: true,
      overflowScroll: true,
      updateHash: true,
      touchScroll: false,
      before:function() {},
      after:function() {},
      afterResize:function() {},
      afterRender:function() {},
    });

  } 
});

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time! it's working :D! You don't know how happy I'm now :D

Comment: Glad I could help! Good luck on the rest of your project - the site looks killer!